# What is the best practice to put Velocity properties when using VelocityViewServlet

Tags: java, servlets, web, velocity, web.xml

I want to use Velocity in a web application in order to add dynamic content from a database to html files. I've configured Velocity successfully by using the `VelocityViewServlet`. My web.xml looks like this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>velocity</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.velocity.tools.view.VelocityViewServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>velocity</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I want to load some content in these way:

```
#set( $pageId = "6655231")
$data.getContent($pageId)
```

Where should I set the property `$data` ?

Should I set the property in a own HttpServlet implementation that extends VelocityViewServlet?

Or is there an other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Velocity View Tools, there should be a [configuration file](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/releases/2.0/view.servlet.html#Toolbox_Configuration) named `WEB-INF/tools.xml` which defines the three toolboxes corresponding to the three nested scopes application, session and request). Those toolboxes can also contain static data.

For instance, if your data accessor object is using the class org.mine.Catalog, your `tools.xml` file could be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tools>
  <toolbox scope="application">
     <tool key="date" class="org.apache.velocity.tools.generic.ComparisonDateTool" locale="en_US"/>
    <tool key="data" class="org.mine.Catalog"/>
  </toolbox>
  <toolbox scope="session">
    <property name="create-session" value="true" type="boolean"/>
    <tool key="map" class="java.util.HashMap"/>
  </toolbox>
  <toolbox scope="request">
    <tool key="custom" class="org.mine.CustomTool" randomProperty="whatever"/>
  </toolbox>
  <data type="string" key="deployment" value="prod"/>
</tools>
```

The [*standard tools*](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/releases/2.0/summary.html) are already included by default in the toolboxes, so you only need to declare custom tools, or standard tools with custom attributes.

To add dynamic content from a database, you can check the [Velosurf](http://velosurf.sourceforge.net/) tool. You can also [write your custom tool](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/releases/2.0/creatingtools.html), it's pretty easy: basically your tool is a plain old java object, with an empty constructor, needed getters and setters, and a `void configure(Map config)` method which receives several environment properties.